# Kotlin: Visibility modifier changes type of anonymous object

Tags: kotlin, extension-methods, class-visibility

Removing the `private` modifier of `myScope` (line 4) in the following working code will break the code. The reason for that is the changing type of `myScope`. Is the visibility set to `private` the type is: `anonymous object : Scope`. Without `private` the type is switched to `Scope`. How can I fix this behavior?

```
interface Scope
operator fun<SD: Scope> SD.invoke(block: SD.() -> Unit) = block()

private val myScope = object : Scope {
    fun Int.myScopedExtFunction() = 1337
}

fun usage() {
    myScope {
        1.myScopedExtFunction()
    }
}
```

Here both versions in Android Studio:
[image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This behavior is by design. See the [documentation](http://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/object-declarations.html):

> Note that anonymous objects can be used as types only in local and private declarations. If you use an anonymous object as a return type of a public function or the type of a public property, the actual type of that function or property will be the declared supertype of the anonymous object, or Any if you didn't declare any supertype. Members added in the anonymous object will not be accessible.